# How to horizontally center a Views field in a grid using CSS field style

Tags: css, drupal, view

I've created a Drupal View using a Grid format that displays a single column of graphics with a title above each. The title and graphic default to the left side. I want to horizontally center them on the page. How do I do that?

I created a CSS class and applied it to both fields. (Field/Style Settings/Create CSS Class/"my style") Still, neither field centers. When I inspect the output, the style appears as a span around the title but is nowhere to be found on the graphic. What am I doing wrong?

The page: http://www.tradecaptain.com/ForexTradeMap. My CSS applied to the two Grid fields:

```
.view-TradeMapHorzCenter{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; }
```

This looks like it should work but...any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to have a width defined for margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
to work.

Without a width defined auto margins don't work.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful tip Andrew! First, I thought the width was defined previously by the page or any other wrappers. Second, why would my CSS appear as a span for the title field and not appear at all for the graphic when I inspect the elements?

Comment: Could you rephrase the second question? I don't think i understand what you mean.

Comment: And if my answer answered your question please mark it as a approved.

Comment: Sure! When I inspect the two elements in the browser, the CSS style appears applied to the text field (though it does not work). The CSS style does not appear around the graphic. Oh, and the width is the page width of 960. It is a single column output.